# Load react native bundle from a server(trying to host it on aws S3) for Android

Tags: react-native

I need to be able to update the bundle on S3 to push out updates instantly to the app but can't figure out how to go through with the bundling and hosting.

I was able to find a few solutions, but all of them are for iOS, this one seem to be the most detailed: https://medium.com/react-native-training/lazy-bundle-loading-in-react-native-5f717b65482a. Is there any way to do the same for android?

Answer (score 0):

If you want instant updates, have a look at [codepush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/). It is like a cloud service, which enables you to deploy mobile app updates directly to your users’ devices.

Here is a [github](https://github.com/microsoft/code-push) page with more explanation.